# Why is image plane not detected by mist pass in EEVEE?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-layers, render-passes

I have a couple of image texture planes in my scene. They render as expected upon applying mist pass in Cycles, but in EEVEE the planes are invisible in the mist pass while other test objects (the spheres) turn out fine. Refer the images.

cycles render:
[image: cycles render]
eevee render:
[image: eevee render]
viewport solid:
[image: viewport solid]
viewport material:
[image: viewport material]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is, But for some reason, mist doesn't render an object in EEVEE with alpha when the alpha setting is set to Alpha blend.

Go to Material Properties-Settings-BlendMode- and change it from Alpha Blend to Alpha clip or Alpha Hashed. and it should hopefully work now.